# Android Buttons Shrinking after I add Background Color

Tags: android, button

I have a relative layout with buttons aligned on the bottom of the screen but for some reason when I add the android:background to the last button it shrinks all the buttons on the screen. Any advice would be great. I'm newer to Android so im still getting used to stuff.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/yoders_red" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttRest"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Restaurant"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="11dp" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttProd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Produce"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttDeli"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Deli"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttGS"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Gift Shop"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#000000">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot of how it looks before and after you make that change?

Answer (score 0):

An Android Button acts sort of like a TextView with a background set to the default Android button. When setting the android:background of a Button, you are replacing the original default button image. The default button image had padding set inside of it's 9 patch drawable.

You have two options.

1. Set the android:padding of all of your buttons until it looks the way you want it.
2. Create a 9 patch drawable that will give the style that you are aiming for. You can find how to make a 9 patch here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Let me know if you would like further explanation of how a 9 patch will change padding. Please read the linked article first though :)